# How to add new column in to a dataset in SAS using proc SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to add a new column to a dataset based on the binary condition of another column. However, I keep getting an error. My code below:

```
proc sql;
alter table data
    add Status (case WHEN missing(DeactReason) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive)'
   END;
quit;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
143  proc sql;
144  alter table data
145      add Status (case WHEN missing(DeactReason) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive)'
                    -
                    79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a CHECK.

146     END;
           -
           79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

147  quit;
```

Thanks!
EDIT:
Corrected the code:

```
proc sql;
alter table table
    add Status (case WHEN missing(DeactReason) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive')
   END;
quit;
```

Get the following error now:

```
148  proc sql;
149  alter table table
150      add Status (case WHEN missing(DeactReason) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive')
                    -                                                            -
                    79                                                           22
                                                                                 76
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a CHECK.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=,
              <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, CONTAINS, END, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS,
              LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

151     END;
152  quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALTER TABLE` statement is used to add new columns, delete existing columns or modifying the format of columns. Afaik you cannot use `CASE` expressions within an alter table statement. You can do it within an `UPDATE` statement though.

```
proc sql;
    alter table data add status char label= "Status" format=$8.;
    update data set status=case when missing(DeactReason) then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the SQL ALTER statement to insert data.

But modifying an existing dataset is not a normal analysis step.  Plus is is dangerous because if something goes wrong you might destroy your original dataset.

Just create a new dataset that has the additional information you want.

With SQL using PROC SQL.

```
proc sql;
  create table new as 
  select *
       , case WHEN missing(DeactReason) THEN 'Active' 
              ELSE 'Inactive' 
         END as STATUS
  from old
  ;
quit;
```

Or with normal SAS code.

```
data new; 
   set old;
   if missing(DeactReason) THEN STATUS='Active  ';
                           ELSE STATUS='Inactive';

run;
```